# Cannot merge an image to a custom background using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

i've been working on my mini project. The project is to paste an image of one product into a custom background, but I couldn't solve it. Here is what I did :
This is an example image

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
foreground = Image.open(FOREGROUND_IMG_FILE).convert('RGBA')
background = Image.new('RGBA',foreground.size,(246,246,246,255))
```

And this is the background image

[image]

I used :
`background.paste(foreground,None,foreground)` `Image.alpha_composite(background,foreground) Image.composite(background,foreground,foreground)`

After created I saved and see, but nothing happen, it was just the original image.. I don't know if PIL has another method of doing this, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The provided image does not have an alpha channel.

Try
    print(foreground)
    print(foreground.getextrema())

and you'll see that the alpha channel is 255 for all pixels after conversion to RGBA.

Output:

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=800x800 at 0x29C7B70> 
((0, 255),  (0, 255), (0, 255), (255, 255))
```

With no transparency the expected output of your operations is the foreground image.